# Closure Compiler, missing method with advanced optimizations?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm using the closure compiler in an angularjs application.  My JS compiles without errors (or warnings) and works fine with SIMPLE optimizations.  Specifically, I have the following warnings/checks enabled:

```
--jscomp_warning=checkTypes \
--jscomp_error=checkVars \
--jscomp_warning=deprecated \
--jscomp_error=duplicate \
--jscomp_warning=globalThis \
--jscomp_warning=missingProperties \
--jscomp_warning=undefinedNames \
--jscomp_error=undefinedVars \
```

However, when I try to compile using ADVANCED OPTIMIZATIONS, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: a.handleEvent is not a function
    at Sj.Nh.a.(anonymous function).a.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:10080/main/pattern.dots-0-7-7-258310cc.compiled.js:118:273)
    at $h (http://app.js:120:424)
    at R (http://app.js:119:337)
    at lj (http://app.js:144:380)
    at Sj.f.re (http://app.js:151:622)
    at mo (http://app.js:302:171)
    at to (http://app.js:316:78)
    at link (http://app.js:308:335)
    ...
```

which appears to be related to event handling code (from looking at the source map):

```
/**
 * @param {Object|Function} listener The listener function or an
 *     object that contains handleEvent method.
 * @return {!Function} Either the original function or a function that
 *     calls obj.handleEvent. If the same listener is passed to this
 *     function more than once, the same function is guaranteed to be
 *     returned.
 */
goog.events.wrapListener = function(listener) {
  goog.asserts.assert(listener, 'Listener can not be null.');

  if (goog.isFunction(listener)) {
    return listener;
  }

  goog.asserts.assert(
      listener.handleEvent, 'An object listener must have handleEvent method.');
  if (!listener[goog.events.LISTENER_WRAPPER_PROP_]) {
    listener[goog.events.LISTENER_WRAPPER_PROP_] =
        function(e) { return listener.handleEvent(e); };
  }
  return listener[goog.events.LISTENER_WRAPPER_PROP_];
};
```

But this seems really odd.  After all, there's an assert a couple lines up that (apparently) passes.  I *think* I've tried to keep the assert (`-D goog.asserts.ENABLE_ASSERTS`) and even if the assert is optimized away, I don't understand why it would work with SIMPLE optimizations (where the assert would still be present).  Also, the code still works if I compile with advanced optimizations and `--debug`, which looks like it starts the process of namespace collapsing, but doesn't go all the way.

Interestingly enough, if I try adding some `console.log` statements:

```
goog.events.wrapListener = function(listener) {
  goog.asserts.assert(listener, 'Listener can not be null.');

  if (goog.isFunction(listener)) {
    return listener;
  }

  goog.asserts.assert(
      listener.handleEvent, 'An object listener must have handleEvent method.');
  if (!listener[goog.events.LISTENER_WRAPPER_PROP_]) {
    listener[goog.events.LISTENER_WRAPPER_PROP_] =
        function(e) {
          console.log(e);
          console.log(listener);
          console.log(typeof listener);
          console.log(listener.handleEvent);
          console.log(typeof listener.handleEvent);
          return listener.handleEvent(e);
        };
  }
  return listener[goog.events.LISTENER_WRAPPER_PROP_];
};
```

And I see that the `typeof listener` is `'function'`.  But if that's the case, how did we get here in the first place?  (certainly `goog.isFunction(listener)` should have returned `true` at that point ...).

I'm a bit at a loss as to what might be going on here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It seems that after countless hours of trying to debug this one, the answer falls into my lap right after I post the question (again).

I was unlucky enough to have `goog.isFunction` compile down to the symbol `ga` -- which conflicts with the global usage tracking library "Google Analytics".

The solution for me was to just include the [`universal_analytics_api.js`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/contrib/externs/universal_analytics_api.js) in my externs and all seems to be well with the world.

Comment: The best protection against this type of collision is to use the `--output_wrapper` flag to add an immediately invoked function wrapper: `--output_wrapper='(function(){"use strict";%output%}).call(this)'`. This prevents renamed symbols from existing in the global scope and colliding with other scripts.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth -- Thanks, that sounds like a good idea so I'll do that.  Kicking the scenarios around in my head, I still think I should include the externs though.